# GNU Octave is not shown in Ubuntu Software center

Tags: apt, package-management, software-center, octave

Using Ubuntu 16.04, I cannot seem to find GNU Octave listed in Ubuntu Software by searching the keyword "Octave":

[image: searching in Ubuntu Software using the keyword Octave]

GNU Octave is not listed in Science or Science -> Math categories either:

[image: GNU Octave not listed in the Science category]

However, the output of `apt-cache search octave` does list

```
octave - GNU Octave language for numerical computations
```

which shows that the repositories are installed and updated properly.

Other online documents show that GNU Octave is supposed to be available in Ubuntu Software center, and that is the way I remember it from previous versions of Ubuntu a few years ago. Why is it not listed anymore?

Comment: It shows up in the old Ubuntu Software Center (still works but needs to be installed). I think the new one, Gnome-based, show more some typical Gnome apps but less of what matters, many software still available for all the current versions.

Comment: @CelticWarrior Is there a rule for what is shown and not shown, or is this a bug? Also, how can I get the old Ubuntu Software Center?